# IOS 8 : Can't use println in Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, println

I'm building an Custom Keyboard.

In viewcontroller, everything is ok.

But that's weird that i can't use println function in keyboard extension.
Nothing can println in console log.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NSLog() instead of println.

Comment: Many tks, i just figure out how to debug. NSLog is work. but only debug with extension, if you are debugging for whole project, NSLog won't work too.

Comment: Good practice for debugging is to use breakpoints and then in console write "po variableName" to print out the value of a variable